# "Access Denied” error while creating Amazon S3 bucket even i have permission as given snipet

Tags: amazon-web-services, vb.net

I am trying to access bucket of Amazon S3 using VB.Net code. Like,

Dim config As AmazonS3Config = New AmazonS3Config
config.ServiceURL = "https://s3-us-west-2.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/scrape-pool/daily"
client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(access_key, secret_access_key, config)
        client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client
        Dim request As New PutObjectRequest()
        Dim S3_KEY As String = "Demo_Create_File_For_Test_AmazonS3.txt"

```
    Try

        request.WithBucketName(bucket_name)
        request.WithKey(S3_KEY)
        request.WithContentBody("This is body of S3 object.")
        client.PutObject(request)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

And,
I have access permission like given below, which is given by my company for accessing Amazon S3 bucket.
But I cannot able to access the bucket.It always shows "Access Denied"
can you suggest Any access privilege that I should have, so i could access the bucket?

{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:*"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::scrape-pool/daily/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::scrape-pool"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Please give any guidance
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That policy statement won't grant you full privileges on the bucket prefix.  The section:

```
{ "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["s3:"], "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::scrape-pool/daily/" ] }
```

Should look like (adding a *):

```
{ "Effect": "Allow", "Action": ["s3:*"], "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::scrape-pool/daily/" ] }
```

This will grant you full S3 permissions on that prefix.

Comment: But the Company will not grant me full access as they have many sensitive data in some s3 buckets so they can't really give my team this kind of access. So is there any other way to do this??